# Distributed databases: What if hardware fails

Tags: bigdata

Let us take some kind of distributed highly available database like Redis, Cassandra, Mongo etc. Replication factor = 5. Read quorum = 3. Write quorum = 3. Now a write occurs, but only 3 out of 5 get updated. So it is a success. But it so happens that one of the 3 successful updates crashes, and the other two are not yet updated. Disk, CPU is fffuttt. Now we have 2 out of 4 successfully updated. How will this be handled? We cannot achieve read quorum of 3/5 anymore. Should this be considered a case of lost data?
Now I understand that in usual case, it is considered that there is a software crash, and the dying instance will restart and everything will be good. This is a case of permanent hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that you have 5 machines in the cluster with the replication factor of 5. That means that every machine holds the same data. That's a very unusual setup.

I'm not sure about Redis or Mongo but in the Cassandra the read quorum will be achieved because more then 3 replicas are alive (4/5 actually).

In Cassandra there is a mechanism that will try to make the data consistent during the read. It's called read repair.
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/read_repair.html